# Count records where their vote count in another table meets a criterion

Tags: mysql, database

SQL beginner here.

I have two tables, comments and votes.  I have comments.id and votes.commentid, which lets me attach votes to a comment.

The tables contains:
comments.id
comments.text

votes.commentid (ref comments.id)
votes.vote (1 or -1)

So people make comments, and other people vote on them.  If people change their vote, it's reflected in the votes table so each person can only vote once, so there's no mass upvoting/downvoting, etc.

---

What I'm trying to do is fetch all the comments that have less than 25% of negative votes.  I am not sure how to write this query.  Anything I do try is simply an SQL error.

So basically I want to do something like (pardon my horrid sql here)

```
select text from comments
where 
count(where votes.commentid=comments.id AND votes.vote<0) <
(count(where votes.commentid=comments.id AND votes.vote>0)*.25)
```

So I have tried everything to my limit of my SQL understanding, and I can't find a syntax that works.  Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT text FROM (SELECT commentid, SUM(IF(vote > 0, 1, 0)) AS pos_votes,
SUM(IF(vote < 0, 1, 0)) AS neg_votes FROM votes GROUP BY commentid) AS vote_count
INNER JOIN comments ON comments.id = vote_count.commentid WHERE
(neg_votes * 100 / (neg_votes + pos_votes)) <= 25
```

Comment: That works!  What a beast of a query, though!  How will it perform speed wise when the comments table starts to get up to 10-20,000?

Comment: Easy answer: indexes. Complex answer: maybe temporary tables, maybe views.

Comment: Well, one thing I could do is update a boolean in the comments table any time anyone votes... so whenever a vote happens, that boolean gets set or un-set, which could help distribute the load... since then the query is just "is this boolean set."